# Illustrator: how to rotate object by specific amount

Tags: adobe-illustrator, rotate

I want to have a text box oriented at an arbitrary angle. I know that I can *rotate* a text box relative to a current orientation, but can I specify the angle of the final orientation? I know that this information exists in Illustrator because if I turn smart guides on and perform a free rotation, a context box tells me the current angle. I would like to be able to do the same thing for a line.

Comment: @Lucian Yeah seems so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform palette has a field where you can enter an amount to rotate an object. And at least on CC 2017, it saves your value.

I highlighted it in the pic below:

[image]